# Подключение java к MS Access при помощи Ucanaccess

Tags: javascript, java, access, ms-access

Доброго времени суток!

Изучать (пытаться писать) Java начал не давно и столкнулся с проблемой к подключению к таблице MS Access (2010). Среда разработки jdk-9.0.4 .
При помощи Maven скачал пакет Ucanaccess 4.0.3, т.к. jdbc:odbc не используется с версии jdk 8

```
`<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ucanaccess/ucanaccess -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

`

Вот сам class

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MSAccess {

public static void main (String args[]) {

try {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
  ("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Java_project/Base_access/db1.mdb", null, null);


Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet resultQuery = statement.executeQuery
("SELECT Nazv_org FROM TABLE abonent");

while (resultQuery.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultQuery.getString(1));
        }
        resultQuery.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

База данных без логина и пароля. Также пытался вводить

2-ой вариант

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Java_project/Base_access/db1.mdb");
```

3-ий вариант

```
Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Java_project/Base_access/db1.mdb", "", "");
```

Если изменить имя файла в то ругается, что файла нет, т.е. файл он находит но почему не подключается, не могу понять.

Вот какие ошибки выводятся

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.3 
unexpected token: ABONENT required: (

at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery
(UcanaccessStatement.java:218)

at MSAccess.MSAccess.main(MSAccess.java:23)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ABONENT 
required: (

at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery
(UcanaccessStatement.java:216)

... 1 more

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: ABONENT required: (
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedTokenRequire(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.readThis(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableFunctionDerivedTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
```

P.S. На Delphi к этой БД подключаюсь без проблем

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена! 
Не правильный SQL запрос

```
("SELECT Nazv_org FROM TABLE abonent")
```

правильный

```
("SELECT Nazv_org FROM abonent")
```